# Cypress load data from json - fixture before

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am trying to retrieve some data from a json file via fixture in Cypress, but the data is not recognized at all.

```
before(() => {
cy.fixture('example').then(function (data) {
    console.log("this", data.user);
})
```

})

The console outputs the user, this is working.

But after that I have a step:

```
Given("I check data", () => {
    console.log("this", this.data.user);
});
```

And here the data is undefined.

I tried to set inside `before` also:

`this.data = data` but did not help. I also tried to use `beforeEach` with no success.

Comment: It's mentioned in the docs here: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture#this-context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a cucumber user, but in plain Cypress tests you can only access `this` by making the callback a function not an arrow function

```
Given("I check data", function() {
  console.log("this", this.data.user);
});
```

I think you might have to alias the data as well

```
before(() => {
  cy.fixture('example')
    .then(function (data) {
      console.log("this", data.user)
    })
    .as('data');
}
```

Note that Cypress clears aliases in between tests, so you would need to use `beforeEach()` instead of `before()`.

Comment: thank you, that was the issue, just to replace arrow function with function. I didn't know about this. Now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned here in the [cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture#this-context)

> If you store and access the fixture data using this test context
> object, make sure to use function () { ... } callbacks. Otherwise the
> test engine will NOT have this pointing at the test context.

Changing the arrow function to function should work:

```
Given("I check data", function() {
    console.log("this", this.example.user);
});
```

And your `beforeEach()` block:

```
   beforeEach(function () {
        cy.fixture('example').then(function (example) {
            this. example = example
        })
    })
```